# help with a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation of the form $$f(y)\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}z} + g(y)=h(z)+K$$ with $K$ constant.
I need to know, what kind of equation is it? and how I can solve it? can be analytically or numerically.